# Place INSERT queries for supporting and type tables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I'm using a database project (not the new database project that comes with [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg427686)) to manage my team database changes and source control benefits.

Now there are some tables that provide simple functionality and are created in the process of normalization. For example: `AddressType` table that may hold these values: Office, Home, and Mail. Now this table will always have these three values.

Can I somehow, using the database project, have the three default values inserted if the table doesn't already have them? If so, where do I put the IF/INSERT script for data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in your post-deployment script:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AddressType WHERE [Name]  = 'Office')
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO AddressType([NAME])
    VALUES ('Office')
END

GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AddressType WHERE [Name]  = 'Home')
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO AddressType([NAME])
    VALUES ('Home')
END

GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AddressType WHERE [Name]  = 'Mail')
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO AddressType([NAME])
    VALUES ('Mail')
END

GO
```

Comment: I thought that would be the correct place. Now I need to discuss with Team Lead.